# WEB API - FromBody parameter is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue with my body parameter being always null.
Here's the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async void Assign([FromUri] int[] sectionIds, [FromBody] int[] ids) ...
```

The URI parameter is filled out. However, The Body parameter is always empty.

Here's the ajax request:

```
    return $.ajax(
        {
            url: api_url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "ids": ids
            })
        })
```

Here's what I see in the payload on in my network monitor.

```
    {"ids":[597,1893]}:
```

What's could be the problem here?

EDIT: I'm using an API Controller

Comment: Does `[FromBody] int[] ids` work if you remove `[FromUri] int[] sectionIds` from action method?

Comment: @Win No, it doesn't work either even without the uri parameter.

Comment: Can you show us the request?

Comment: Could you add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in Ajax and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up using simple types. Nothing worked and I wasted alot of time on this.

I tried the similar solutions as this one: http://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/

But it does not work with arrays, the array had only 1 value of 0.
So, as a workaround I created a complex type and encapsulated my 2 parameters in it.

```
// Controller code
[HttpPost]
public async void Assign([FromBody] AssignModel) ...
```

Client code

```
// Client code
    return $.ajax(
        {
            url: api_url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "Ids": ids,
                "SectionIds": sectionIds
                })
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that URL is not in correct place. Could you try the following with **contentType**?

```
$.ajax({
   url: API_URL,
   contentType: "application/json",
   method: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({"ids": ids}, 
   success: function(result) { return result; }
});
```

Comment: I tried your change, same issue here. The ids array is still null

Comment: Could you try sending string value instead of array just for testing?

Comment: see my answer below. A string value was working indeed, but the array did not.

Answer (score 2):

Your body must be value of json, not a json with parameter name and value.
In your case it must be:

```
POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 7
[1,2]
```

In javascript something like:

```
return $.ajax(
{
    url: api_url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: [1,2]
})
```

Comment: What is `[1,2]`?

Comment: @xr280xr The ids in the body. It actually works, tried it with Swagger.